# Movie database browser

Tags: php, optimization

My code looks like "spaghetti code". I have yet to use OOP in PHP but I am really interested in how a good programmer would handle this many `if` statements. It looks like a mess.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include './functions.php';

    if(empty($_FILES['browseMovie']) || empty($_FILES['browseThumbnail']) || empty($_GET['title']) || empty($_GET['description']))
    {
        die('Please insert all fields.');
    }

    $filePartsMovie = pathinfo($_FILES['browseMovie']['name']);
    $filePartsThumbnail = pathinfo($_FILES['browseThumbnail']['name']);

    if($filePartsMovie['extension'] !== "mp4")
    {
        die('Video has to be a .mp4 file.');
    }

    if($filePartsThumbnail['extension'] !== "jpg" && $filePartsThumbnail['extension'] !== "png")
    {
        die('Thumbnail has to be in jpg/jpeg or png format.');
    }

    if($_FILES['browseMovie']['size'] + $_FILES['browseThumbnail']['size'] > 1600600000)
    {
        die('filesize of video and thumbnail = higher 1.5 GB.');
    }

    $id = $_SESSION["id"];
    $name = $_SESSION["username"];
    $folderName = generateUniqueFolder();
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']);
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['description']);

    // the original file name will be stored in the database as well
    $thumbFileName = basename($_FILES['browseThumbnail']['name']);
    $vidFileName = basename($_FILES['browseMovie']['name']);

    $userDir = "../users/$name/";
    $videoDir = $userDir . "videos/" . $folderName . "/";

    $uploadMovieDir =  $videoDir . $vidFileName;
    $uploadThumbnailDir = $videoDir . $thumbFileName;

    if(!isLoggedIn() || !is_dir($userDir))
    {
        die('User does not have own folder. Please contact the administrator.');
    }

    if(!mkdir($videoDir))
    {
        die('Could not create unique video folder.');
    }

    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['browseMovie']['tmp_name'], $uploadMovieDir))
    {
        rmdir($videoDir);
        die('Could not upload the video correctly.');
    }

    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['browseThumbnail']['tmp_name'], $uploadThumbnailDir))
    {
        removeTreeDir($videoDir);
        die('Could not upload the thumbnail correctly.');
    }

    $con = connectDb();
    $videoQuery = "INSERT INTO video(userId, title, description, foldername, vidFileName, thumbFileName) VALUES ($id,'$title','$description','$folderName', '$vidFileName', '$thumbFileName')";

    if(!mysql_query($videoQuery))
    {
        removeTreeDir($videoDir);
        die('Could not add the video to the database.');
    }

    mysql_close($con);

    echo "true";
?>
```

Somewhere in the middle of my code I also need a bunch of variables. How would one clean that up? Create an object and aggregate them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first if can be simplifed with `any` function.

```
function any ($list, $pred) 
{
     foreach ($list as $value) 
     {
          if (call_user_func ($pred, $value) == TRUE)
             return TRUE;
     }
     return FALSE;
}
```

So it will be :

```
 $toTest = [$_FILES['browseMovie'], 
            $_FILES['browseThumbnail'], 
            $_GET['title'], 
            $_GET['description'] ]
 if (any ($toTest, "empty")) die ("Please insert all fields")
```

Then you can simplify the code even more by creating a `validate` type function

```
function validateFile ($filePartsMovie, $filePartsThumbnail) 
{
      if($filePartsMovie['extension'] !== "mp4")
      {
           die('Video has to be a .mp4 file.');
      }

      if($filePartsThumbnail['extension'] !== "jpg" &&
         $filePartsThumbnail['extension'] !== "png")
      {
          die('Thumbnail has to be in jpg/jpeg or png format.');
      } 

     if($_FILES['browseMovie']['size'] + $_FILES['browseThumbnail']['size'] > 1600600000)
     {
              die('filesize of video and thumbnail = higher 1.5 GB.');
     }
}
```

Then you can create a validate function for the rest of the code.

TLDR is to split your code in more separate functions.

BTW I think you do not need brackets when having only one statement after `if`.

Comment: I do not know PHP so this is from my general programming knowledge. It might not work, but the idea behind the code I posted is good (I hope :))

Comment: Doesnt matter really :) This can happen in any language. It just happened to be written in php when I came across this problem.

Comment: BTW, I like your validateFile() function. That would definitely make it more organized. :) I dont know about the top one, though. I only need to check if they're empty once. Is that worth the effort adding extra code?

Comment: "BTW I think you do not need brackets when having only one statement after if." -- You don't, but I nearly always use them for readability.

Comment: Indeed, braceless syntax is allowed, but is usually frowned upon. Additionally that short array syntax ([] instead of array()) is relatively new to PHP (5.4) and may be confusing if someone is unfamiliar with it and attempts to use it with an older version.